# Como criar um método único para tratar erros com ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tenho um aplicativo web que executa varias chamadas **ajax**. O meu professor da faculdade me desafiou a criar uma mensagem genérica e unir o tratamento de erro todo em uma única função. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

```
function getShoes() {

    $.get( "/Shoes/List", function( data ) {
        shoes = data;
    }).fail(function() {
        toastr.error('Erro ao buscar sapatos')
    });
}

function getCoats() {

    $.get( "/Coats/List", function( data ) {
        coats = data;
    }).fail(function() {
        toastr.error('Erro ao buscar casacos')
    });
}
```

Comment: basicamente, a tarefa é eliminar redundâncias. Onde há repetição de códigos, vc deve automatizar, deixar de um jeito mais genérico numa única função que execute tais processos já que os parâmetros e o retorno são os mesmos.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode utilizar os eventos globais do ajax do jQuery, por exemplo o [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/). Sempre que uma solicitação do Ajax é concluída com um erro, o jQuery dispara o evento [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) nele você pode adicionar seu tratamento, conforme o código abaixo:

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function() {
     //sua menssagem de erro genérica
     toastr.error('Problemas ao buscar os dados!')
});
```

Implementação em cima de seu código:

```
/*executa após todo conteudo ser carregado*/
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /*adiciona o evento global no ready da sua pagina*/
    $( document ).ajaxError(function() {
         //sua menssagem de erro genérica
         toastr.error('Problemas ao buscar os dados!');
    });    
});

/*agora você pode editar suas funções retirando o evento do fail,
pois todos os erros serão tratados acima. Centralizando assim os erros*/
function getShoes() {

    $.get( "/Shoes/List", function( data ) {
        shoes = data;
    });
}

function getCoats() {

    $.get( "/Coats/List", function( data ) {
        coats = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: Era exatamente isto que meu professor queria, muito obrigado me ajudou muito

Comment: Que bom que deu certo! estou a disposição :))

Answer (score 2):

Da maneira que o @Brunno fez, você estaria definindo um erro que seria padrão para todos as requisições XHR da sua página.

Uma outra maneira de fazer é declarar uma função que retorne o erro como meio de reutilização de código e, em seguida, chamá-las como parâmetro de `fail`.

Veja:

```
function ajaxError()
{
     console.log('Problemas ao buscar os dados!');
}
```

Em seguida basta passar o nome da função como parâmetro de `fail`

```
function getShoes() {

    $.get( "/Shoes/List", function( data ) {
        shoes = data;
    });
    .fail(ajaxError);
}

function getCoats() {

    $.get( "/Coats/List", function( data ) {
        coats = data;
    })
    .fail(ajaxError);
}
```