# Como mostrar tela de "carregando" com modal bootstrap em qualquer processo do servidor c#

Tags: c#, jquery, modal, bootstrap

Necessito de que as minhas páginas mostrem a todo processo do servidor uma tela com um tipo de *Carregando* usando o modal bootstrap que criei abaixo. Meu problema é conseguir mostrar isso em todos os processos.

- Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?
- Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Meu código:

```
<div class="container">
                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="modalProcessando" tabindex="-1"
                    role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h4 class="modal-title">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time">
                                    </span>&nbsp;Aguarde
                                    </h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <div class="progress">
                                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info
                                    progress-bar-striped active"
                                    style="width: 100%">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso para todos os ajax da sua aplicação, utilizando os eventos  [**globais**](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).

Exemplo:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function () {
    ///chama seu processando
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    //finaliza seu processando
});
```

Você também pode usar o `.ajaxError()` para criar um tratamento de erro global, conforme expliquei [**aqui**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/85277/30045).

Comment: agradeço pela informação que me passou, mas aparentemente não funciona pra o que eu quero.. esse procedimento executa perfeitamente na abertura da página, mas em todos os procedimentos restantes nada acontece.. será que estou fazendo algo errado? tem alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: @AlisonVieira, então amigo, esse processo ele vai funcionar só para suas requisições ajax. para as de mais eu uso nas minhas aplicações de uma forma um pouco diferente. Crio a waitbar apartir de uma class especifica e deixo a mesma no body de todas as minhas paginas, ao finalizar o carregamento com $(document).ready eu removo a class.

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo pela sua ajuda.. na verdade a dica que você me passou não resolveu, mas eu encontrei outra forma de fazer que funcionou perfeitamente como eu queria.. apenas defino o onchange de todos os controles que preciso desse processo e quando termina eu apenas faço a chamada para fechar o modal.. de qualquer forma, vou definir sua resposta como correta, pois nos testes eu percebi que funciona também, para outras formas de se fazer.. =D